# How to clip PathFigure with shape?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Need a brainstorm. I want to solve the following problem. [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE7rj.jpg)
Lines (selected) should be absent.

```
<Path  Name="form" Fill="#FF2D7C7C" Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible" StrokeThickness="0.5" >
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry> 
                    <PathFigure x:Name="forme"  StartPoint="205, 142.5">
                        <PolyQuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="form_gg" Points="231.5, 162.5  258, 142.5,
                                                    276, 140.5 284, 147.3,
                                                    285, 190.3 260, 248.3,
                                                    269, 248.3 203, 248.3
                                                    176, 190.3 179.4, 147.3,
                                                    187.4, 140.3, 205, 142.5" >

                        </PolyQuadraticBezierSegment>
                    </PathFigure>


                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Polyline Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"
                  Points="205, 145, 205, 255, 215, 145, 215, 255, 225, 145"></Polyline>
```

Please help to realize the task.

Comment: So remove them. What did you try?

Comment: I wanted to apply the Clip property. Not applicable.

Comment: You want to clip what with what?

Comment: PolyQuadraticBezierSegment with Polyline.